# Can not get html elements working with joint js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jointjs

I have created a simple project to test out joint js. I can not get the html elements to show on the page. I have copied code straight from their web site it results in the screen shot below. You will notice however from the screen shot that I can render a basic svg canvas with two simple boxes. The issue only seems to be with the html elements. I have included all the code I am using. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

[screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF5NF.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
  var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: 650,
    height: 400,
    gridSize: 1,
    model: graph
  });

  // Create a custom element.
  // ------------------------

  joint.shapes.html = {};
  joint.shapes.html.Element = joint.shapes.basic.Rect.extend({
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
      type: 'html.Element',
      attrs: {
        rect: {
          stroke: 'none',
          'fill-opacity': 0
        }
      }
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults)
  });

  // Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

  joint.shapes.html.ElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

    template: [
      '<div class="html-element">',
      '<button class="delete">x</button>',
      '<label></label>',
      '<span></span>', '<br/>',
      '<select><option>--</option><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>',
      '<input type="text" value="I\'m HTML input" />',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
      joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

      this.$box = $(_.template(this.template)());
      // Prevent paper from handling pointerdown.
      this.$box.find('input,select').on('mousedown click', function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
      });
      // This is an example of reacting on the input change and storing the input data in the cell model.
      this.$box.find('input').on('change', _.bind(function(evt) {
        this.model.set('input', $(evt.target).val());
      }, this));
      this.$box.find('select').on('change', _.bind(function(evt) {
        this.model.set('select', $(evt.target).val());
      }, this));
      this.$box.find('select').val(this.model.get('select'));
      this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', _.bind(this.model.remove, this.model));
      // Update the box position whenever the underlying model changes.
      this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);
      // Remove the box when the model gets removed from the graph.
      this.model.on('remove', this.removeBox, this);

      this.updateBox();
    },
    render: function() {
      joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
      this.paper.$el.prepend(this.$box);
      this.updateBox();
      return this;
    },
    updateBox: function() {
      // Set the position and dimension of the box so that it covers the JointJS element.
      var bbox = this.model.getBBox();
      // Example of updating the HTML with a data stored in the cell model.
      this.$box.find('label').text(this.model.get('label'));
      this.$box.find('span').text(this.model.get('select'));
      this.$box.css({
        width: bbox.width,
        height: bbox.height,
        left: bbox.x,
        top: bbox.y,
        transform: 'rotate(' + (this.model.get('angle') || 0) + 'deg)'
      });
    },
    removeBox: function(evt) {
      this.$box.remove();
    }
  });

  // Create JointJS elements and add them to the graph as usual.
  // -----------------------------------------------------------

  var el1 = new joint.shapes.html.Element({
    position: {
      x: 80,
      y: 80
    },
    size: {
      width: 170,
      height: 100
    },
    label: 'I am HTML',
    select: 'one'
  });
  var el2 = new joint.shapes.html.Element({
    position: {
      x: 370,
      y: 160
    },
    size: {
      width: 170,
      height: 100
    },
    label: 'Me too',
    select: 'two'
  });
  var l = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: {
      id: el1.id
    },
    target: {
      id: el2.id
    },
    attrs: {
      '.connection': {
        'stroke-width': 5,
        stroke: '#34495E'
      }
    }
  });

  graph.addCells([el1, el2, l]);




});
```

```css
#paper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#paper svg {
  background: transparent;
}
#paper svg .link {
  z-index: 2;
}
.html-element {
  position: absolute;
  background: #3498DB;
  /* Make sure events are propagated to the JointJS element so, e.g. dragging works.*/
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #2980B9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black, 2px 2px 1px gray;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}
.html-element select,
.html-element input,
.html-element button {
  /* Enable interacting with inputs only. */
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.html-element button.delete {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: #C0392B;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.html-element button.delete:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.html-element select {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 28px;
}
.html-element input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 16px;
}
.html-element label {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.html-element span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 9px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.5/joint.css" />


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.5/joint.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body id="app">
  <div id="paper">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your custom elements before you create the paper. This is due to the new feature (`cellViewNamespace`) that allows for setting custom namespace for your shapes. Try this:

```
joint.shapes.html = {};
joint.shapes.html.Element = ...

...

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: 650,
    height: 400,
    gridSize: 1,
    model: graph
});
```